# I want to turn off output in pytest console

Tags: python, pytest

I want to turn off output in Pytest console, so I can  see **only** my logs.
I tried `pytest -x -s -tb=no` but it's not exactly what I want.

I want to get rid of this output:

```
======================================================== test session starts =========================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.7, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\...\projects\autotest-lk\source
collected 6 items
```

Any advices?

Comment: Rather than anything pytest-specific, I think you want to just redirect the output to null, as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/132963/windows-redirect-stdout-and-stderror-to-nothing).